# Nhibernate order of saving objects

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm having a service which takes a one or more of entities, which has been deserialized from a file. 
These entities may or may not have a relation. 
Are there any easy way to ensure that Nhibernate handles the entities in the correct order when calling saving the entities? 
Right now I'm doing it with `session.Save(entity)` , but it may end up some times end up with an exception about " property pointing at a transient or null value.." .

Answer (score 0):

In general, no, NHibernate will manage it for you automatically because it is considered the safe way. There are two options:

**First option**: You can perform a `Flush` method and make sure you have the executed over the database. For sample:

```
using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var item1 in data1)
            {
                session.Save(item1);
            }
            session.Flush(); // execute all the queries for the itens (1)

            foreach (var item2 in data2)
            {
                session.Save(item2);
            }
            session.Flush(); // execute all the queries for the itens (2)

            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {   
            transaction.RollBack();
            // do some log with `e` exception reference
        }
    }
}
```

**Second option**. If you just need to send it to the database without any state management, you could use `ISessionStateless` instead of classical `ISession`. You lose all the sesion state management that NHibernate does automatically. (lazy loading, first/second level caching, etc..). You just call method like `Insert`, `Delete`, `Update` a entity. Importante: You can have more performance with a `StatelessSession`  give you make sure it is appropriate for your scenario:

https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/batch.html